# Is there a direct way to convert each pandas row into a dictionary or list?

Tags: python, pandas

```
            df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t')
            property_names = list(df)
            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                // how to get a dict from the 'row' here?
```

I can iterate the property_names and use each as key to retrieve its value from row:

```
   row_dict = {} 
   for property_name in property_names:
        row_dict[property_name] = row[property_name]
```

This should work, but is there direct way to convert the row into a dict?

Comment: Do you want to convert each row to a  new dict? Why?

Comment: And exactly why would you want to do that?

Comment: `dict(zip(property_names, row))`?

Comment: dict is easier to work with the pd row?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want to achieve, but a lot of operations in pandas are vectorized, which tends to be more efficient. Furthermore you can use `apply` when easy vectorization is not possible. See this for a nice overview: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html

Answer (score 1):

While I don't quite understand why one would want to do this, a possible solution is:

```
df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

This will give you a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary represents a row.